# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

Tags: android

I am following steps to fetch data from Linkedin.     But I am getting error:

04-25 15:19:09.516    3078-3078/app.plusconnect.com.linkedindummy E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

//declaration
SocialAuthAdapter adapter;
Button linkedin_button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    adapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());

    linkedin_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SubmitButton);
    linkedin_button.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.linkedin);

    linkedin_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            adapter.authorize(MainActivity.this, Provider.LINKEDIN);
        }
    });

}

public class ResponseListener implements DialogListener {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle bundle) {

        adapter.getUserProfileAsync(new ProfileDataListener());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(SocialAuthError socialAuthError) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onBack() {
    }
}

public class ProfileDataListener implements SocialAuthListener<Profile> {

    @Override
    public void onExecute(String s, Profile profile) {
        Log.d("Custom-UI", "Receiving Data");
        Profile profileMap = profile;
        Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Validate ID         = " + profileMap.getValidatedId());
        Log.d("Custom-UI",  "First Name          = " + profileMap.getFirstName());
        Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Last Name           = " + profileMap.getLastName());
        Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Email               = " + profileMap.getEmail());
        Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Country                  = " + profileMap.getCountry());
        Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Language                 = " + profileMap.getLanguage());
        Log.d("Custom-UI",  "Location                 = " + profileMap.getLocation());
        Log.d("Custom-UI", "Profile Image URL  = " + profileMap.getProfileImageURL());

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(SocialAuthError socialAuthError) {
    }
}

}
```

this is the layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textMessage"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Test Connect application like to fetch Profile details from LinkedIn Account."/>

<!-- Submit button -->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/SubmitButton"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:text="Fetch from LinkedIn"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

I am getting following error in logcat:

```
04-25 15:19:09.456    3078-3078/app.plusconnect.com.linkedindummy     W/ResourceType﹕ No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
04-25 15:19:09.477    3078-3078/app.plusconnect.com.linkedindummy W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
04-25 15:19:09.516    3078-3078/app.plusconnect.com.linkedindummy E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1018)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:663)
        at org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthDialog.setUpTitle(SocialAuthDialog.java:191)
        at org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthDialog.onCreate(SocialAuthDialog.java:146)
        at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:353)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:257)
        at org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthAdapter$4$1.run(SocialAuthAdapter.java:649)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Where is the problem? Can anybody help please?

Comment: what is at line `SocialAuthAdapter.java:649`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SocialAuth` requires an image in the `drawable` folder for every service you want to integrate.

You probably don't have these images, and `SocialAuth` crash when try to load the image. To resolve the issue just put an image (e.g. [linkedin.png](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/3pillarlabs/socialauth-android/master/socialauth-android/res/drawable/linkedin.png), [twitter.png](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/3pillarlabs/socialauth-android/master/socialauth-android/res/drawable/twitter.png), [facebook.png](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/3pillarlabs/socialauth-android/master/socialauth-android/res/drawable/facebook.png)) for every service you want to use into `drawable` folder.

Comment: I did,i even put all the pngs for all services provided by it but still i am getting this:No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000   and android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0. Wht could be other possible problem can you please help?

Comment: I just notice that you have a resource named linkedin in `mipmap` folder. Are you sure that the service images are in the `drawable` folder?

Comment: in the updated version of android studio,even if i add images inside drawable folder i can access only through mipmap folder

Comment: I think this is the cause of the issue. Using the file explorer of your OS, open `res` folder, and check if there is `drawable` folder. If it's not available create manually and then put the images inside this folder. After that return to Android Studio and press _Sync Project with Gradle Files_. Now you should see the drawable directory with the image of the services, and the issue should be resolved

Comment: This worked thanks a lott!! There was a drawable folder but it is empty .I added all the images inside drawable folder and it worked. Thank you sso much :) :)

Comment: I thought it's weird solution, but it works now, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please check that  linkedin image is there ?

```
 linkedin_button.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.linkedin);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all LinkedIn Introduced new Mobile SDK for Android.The official support you will get if your using only https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk.

Give a look it's very simple.preferring to use Android Studio for LinkedIn integration.

Comment: converting the sdk to android studio module little bit difficult so better you download it from https://www.dropbox.com/s/73otcg660ktd29x/linkedin-sdk.zip?dl=0 and it need the support of volley https://www.dropbox.com/s/paklb98mlylrrwm/Volley.zip?dl=0 . This done with android studio.

Comment: accept the answer if it might helped you.check my stack overflow account have queries and answers related to this:) http://stackoverflow.com/users/4009562/justin-kominar official supporter

Answer (score 0):

when you receive this kind of error

```
 Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0 xamarin
```

then please go to resources folder in android project and name your image file in small character